# Using Do While loop take input until user get 1

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop, do-while

I want multiple input until user can't get 1. This will not work properly. In this case, can I take multiple edit text box, or not? Please tell me.

```
TextView tv;
EditText et;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.evenodd2);

    tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewevenoddA);
    et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextevenodd);
    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonevenoddA);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String a1;
            int num;
            do
            {
                a1=et.getText().toString();
                num=Integer.parseInt(a1);
                if (num < 1)
                    tv.setText("Wrong Input");
                if (num > 1 && num % 2 == 0)
                {
                    tv.setText("Value is: "+num / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    tv.setText("Value is :"+num);
                }
            }
            while (num != 1);
            tv.setText("Thank You");

        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use a loop here.  You'd do the processing exactly once every time the user presses the button.  A loop getting input is how a console would work, but its not how a GUI driven program reacts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give control back to the swing thread, so the user has a chance to change the input. This loop goes continuously, you need to return from the onClick() so the Event Dispatch Thread has a chance to wait for the user to change the value and click the button again.

Comment: Can you please show me the coding that how I will do I cant't understand please